Linux Docker compose container cannot ping another bridged Docker container
Overview
I need a Docker Compose zabbix host to ping a host on a containerlab docker network.
These two Docker networks run under a linux Docker host machine as below...  This information comes from docker network inspect <statics|zabbix6_statics>...



Name
Driver
Subnet
GW
Internal




statics
bridge
192.0.2.0/24
None
false


zabbix6_statics
bridge
172.25.0.0/16
172.25.0.1
false



My Docker host can ping a statics Docker container at 192.0.2.2; however, one of my Docker compose containers on zabbix6_statics cannot ping that same statics container at 192.0.2.2.
My problem is I am not sure how to control the GW setup for the statics Docker network, it is automatically built by containerlab.
Docker host external interface, routing table and routing configuration:
$ ip addr show ens160
2: ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:a7:82:54 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp3s0
    inet 10.100.50.5/28 brd 10.100.50.15 scope global ens160
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fea7:8254/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
$
$ ip route show
default via 10.100.50.1 dev ens160 proto static
10.100.50.0/28 dev ens160 proto kernel scope link src 10.100.50.5
172.25.0.0/16 dev br-2f0c8e39d468 proto kernel scope link src 172.25.0.1
192.0.2.0/24 dev br-3b7a04204493 proto kernel scope link src 192.0.2.1
$
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
$

Docker host iptables -L...
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (6 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.25.0.3           tcp dpt:zabbix-trapper
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.25.0.4           tcp dpt:http-alt

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (6 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* set by containerlab */
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
$

iptables drops... the line with 573K drops (below) sure looks like it could be a problem, but I don't know how to remove this line.
br-2f0c8e39d468 is the Docker Compose Zabbix bridge network.
$ sudo iptables -L -v -n | grep DROP
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 1 packets, 48 bytes)
 5887  573K DROP       all  --  *      br-2f0c8e39d468  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      br-3b7a04204493  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      br-9c380974ca10  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  128 19232 DROP       all  --  *      br-8852215d128f  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      br-9eb46ec5c23e  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
$

I think the iptables rule applied automatically by the Docker Compose yaml is part of the problem (see below).
Problem
From a Docker Compose Zabbix container on 172.25.0.0/16, I can ping 192.0.2.1 (the linux bridge ip address for Docker network 192.0.2.0/24), but I cannot ping the containerlab Docker container at 192.0.2.2.
The zabbix web gui can accessed from the Docker host via http://10.100.50.5:9000.  The Docker host ip address is 10.100.50.5.
Question
The most important task is just getting the Docker Compose zabbix6_statics network to successfully ping into the Docker statics network (i.e. Docker containers on 172.25.0.0/16 ping 192.0.2.2).
I really don't care what kind of linux kludge fixes or iptables work needs to be done to make pings between the container bridges work right.

The problem is that by default, Docker Compose sets up iptables rules that block traffic to other linux networks on the same docker host.
In this case, I want to allow all traffic to and from my Docker Compose bridge network... to do this, I configured:
sudo iptables -I INPUT -i br-2f0c8e39d468 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i br-2f0c8e39d468 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -o br-2f0c8e39d468 -j ACCEPT

Where br-2f0c8e39d468 is linux Docker host interface corresponding to the Docker Compose bridge.
